# Raspberry Pi and javaFX command error

Tags: java, linux, javafx, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a question.
I´ve created a javaFX application but now i want to run it on my raspberry pi.
JDK 1.8.0 is on my raspberry pi so it can run javaFX applications.
But what command do I have to use?
I hope someone can help me with this problem.
Thank you very much already :)
Gr. Gilian Joosen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an eample command on how to use the .jar file:

sudo /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java -Djavafx.platform=eglfb -cp /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar:/home/pi/javafx-samples-8.0.0-ea/StopWatch.jar stopwatch.MainScreen

The first part of the command (/opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java) contains the address where you have installed java on RPi and the second part (/home/pi/javafx-samples-8.0.0-ea/StopWatch.jar) contains the address of the saved .jar file which is followed by it's class.